# Delete Files older than 30 days

Tags: powershell

```
$Exclude = @("Folder_1","Folder-2","~snapshot")  
$path = "\\\Server\Test"
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $PATH -Recurse -Force |
         Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit} |
         Remove-Item -Force
```

I am trying to delete all files which are older then 30 days but except some folders inside that path which are defined as `$Exclude`.

I have 2 problems when executing this code:

1. `Remove-Item` could not delete files with longer then 248 characters.
2. I don't know how to define the exclusions (they are not allowed to be deleted).

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? There's an easy way around the max path length, but it requires PS 5.1.

Comment: I'm using PSVersion: 4.0

Comment: The path issue is a limit with the standard Windows subsystem and has existed since very early windows versions. I think your only other option is to use a library like [AlphaFS](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS) that has support for extended length paths. If you had the newer version of PS you could just use `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '\\?\UNC\server\test' -Recurse`

Comment: thanks alot for fast replies. I really dont use Powershell too often but I think it might be possible to Upgrade my PS to the newest Version?

Comment: Yep, you install [WMF 5.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616) which includes PowerShell -- as it upgrades multiple components check that it won't break anything else you use. (Will prob be fine on a workstation, but I'd not install on a live Server without checking first)

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir C:\delete
robocopy "\\Server\Test" "c:\Delete" /E /MOVE /MINLAD:30 /LOG:"C:\temp\DeleteOldFiles.txt" /XD "This folder will not be deleted" /FAT 
rmdir c:\delete /s /q
```

That is how I solved this Problem. this one is tested and worked!